# Azure Cent OS Unmounts my data Drive

Tags: centos, mount, azure

I have a Cent OS VM instance running on Windows Azure. I have a 1TB data drive mounted to that VM to hold an application's database files. Every week or so at inconsistent intervals, my database crashes and I find that my data drive has been automatically, and without my permission, unmounted.

My data drive still exists with all the data in tact. I have to log in and remount "sudo mount /dev/sdd1 /mount/datadrive". This is frustrating and harmful to my data and the processes that use it.

What am I doing wrong? Any idea why this is happening? How can i make it stop. THANK YOU.

Comment: Check the logs?

Comment: Yep, there's nothing in the logs prior to the unmounting and nothing about the drive being unmounted. It's like my drive gets unmounted and the logs wiped clean. I'm not a linux expert. Do logs get wiped on a reboot? Is my machine getting rebooted and my drives not being re-mounted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did the machine reboot? did you check uptime? if you didn't add the drive to fstab and the machine rebooted for any reason, your drive will not be mounted.

Microsoft always having issues keeping stuff up and running.

Comment: It's possible that the host server may have been updated which would prompt an update. The best way make sure you're application stays online if/when this happens would be to implement the availability sets.